# How to troubleshoot DDEV DB container healthcheck timeout

Tags: ddev

When i want to start my DDEV Project an Container stucks at creating

```
Container ddev-oszimt-lf12a-v2-db  Started
```

Error Message:

```
Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready: db container failed: log=, err=health check timed out after 2m0s: labels map[com.ddev.site-name:oszimt-lf12a-v2 com.docker.compose.service:db] timed out without becoming healthy, status=
```

Its an Error i also had with some other projects.
In the Error Log is no information about this.

What could the Problem be and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very good place to study problems with specific projects, our [Discord Channel](https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k) is much better, or the [DDEV issue queue](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues).

But I'll try to give you some ideas about how to study and debug this.

1. Go to the [Troubleshooting](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/) section of the docs. Work through it step-by-step.
2. As it says there, try the simplest possible project and see what the results are.
3. If the problem is particular to one particular project, see if you can remove customizations like `.ddev/docker-compose.*.yaml` files and `config.*.yaml` and non-standard things in the config.yaml file.
4. To find out what the causes the healthcheck timeout, see the [docs on this exact problem](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#ddev-start-fails-with-container-failed-to-become-ready), in your case the `db` container is timing out. So first, `ddev logs -s db` to see if something happened, and second `docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" ddev-<projectname>-db`.

For more help, you'll need to provide more information with things like your OS, Docker Provider, etc, and the easiest way to do that is to run `ddev debug test` and capture the output and put it in a gist on gist.github.com, then come over to discord with a link to that.